# Issues with WiFi-WiFi Tor Proxy

Tags: raspbian, iptables

### **Background**

I am currently trying to build a `portable Tor Router` on my `Raspberry Pi 3`.

So I have my Pi 3 with two wireless interfaces, one is a station and the other is an AP.

`wlan0` (station) - Connected to the internet via my desired SSID under `/etc/network/interface`

`wlan1` (AP) - Other clients connect to it.

I would like the clients connected to `wlan1` (AP)  to be able to access the internet on `wlan0`.

Most tutorials out there on the Web have you do the following which routes traffic from `eth0` to `wlan0`:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED \ 
         -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

However, this defeats the purpose of being 100% portable because you still need to connect the Pi with an ethernet cable.

So, I modified the above line to route traffic from `wlan1`  to `wlan0`:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o wlan1 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED \
         -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

I also modified the `/etc/network/interface` file to connect to my home router.

### **Issue**

After modifying `hostapd.conf` to create a AP on `wlan1` and starting the service, `hostapd` takes down `wlan0` as well as all other interfaces that aren't involved with the AP.

How can I make it so that `hostapd` runs in the background and `wlan0` is able to connect to my desired SSID using the configurations under `/etc/network/interface`?

Or even better, how can I make it so that wlan0 is able to connect to ANY SSID, at home, in public, anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and run the following script as `sudo`:

`pifi.sh` : https://github.com/NicholasAdamou/PiFi/raw/master/pifi.sh

It's a script that I made to fix the above issue.

**How did I fix it?**

The HostAPD binary didn't have the correct firmware for the wireless adapter I was using.

The above script will allow you to setup a a `Raspberry Pi` as a `PiFi Wireless Repeater`.

Answer (score -2):

Found this:

https://github.com/saysudo/raspberry-pi-vpn-hotspot/blob/master/Raspberry%20Pi%203%20Model%20B%20as%20VPN%20Hotspot.md

You can skip setting up VPN.

Comment: Please consider adding a little bit more description than just a link.

Comment: As @Shan-Desai mentioned, link only answers are discouraged on this site as they tend to suffer from link rot. Please expand on your answer so that it includes the highlights from your link. If you don't do so within 48 hours, your question will be converted to a community wiki post per the site's community policy.